# Custom Web API oAuth Authentication

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth

I have an interesting scenario in which I need to build a Web API with custom authentication, as dictated by the Client that will be connecting to my Web API Service. (Usually it's the Service that defines the contract, but for this project it's the other way around, sadly).

So I have the 'standard' OAuthAuthorization configured and working as per the standard Visual Studio Web API Project template.

When a client makes the following request to the /token endpoint:

> curl -X POST "http://localhost:2432/Token" -d
>   "grant_type=password&userName=MyUserName&password=MyPassword"

the endpoint returns the following token:

```
{
  "access_token": "the full token is here...",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "expires_in": 1209599,
  "userName": "MyUserName",
  ".issued": "Mon, 05 Sep 2016 17:35:08 GMT",
  ".expires": "Mon, 19 Sep 2016 17:35:08 GMT"
}
```

Now, I need to change the server so as to accept the following structure of token request instead:

> curl -u "MyUserName:MyPassword" -X GET "http://server/api/token"

and the token that gets returned needs to be as per the following structure:

```
{"id":"generated GUID here"}
```

Then in subsequent requests to the service, the GUID will be included in a custom header:

> curl -H "X-CrmIService-Token: generated GUID here" -X GET "http://server/api/protectedResource"

I'm happy with the concept of having to add a custom Authorize Filter to use the custom header to authorize requests to the protected resources.

But I need guidance on how to configure and set up my authorization middleware to get the login request to work.

Requests of the second structure mentioned above fail out of the blocks with the server returning

```
{"error":"unsupported_grant_type"}
```

before hitting any breakpoint I set in the solution.

Please advise how I need to configure my authorization middleware?

Answer (score 1):

The change you're looking at is not really the way OAuth2 works.
OAuth2 is supposed to be application level authorization, not user level.

Imagine you build a web app which uses an OAuth2 api. 
The clientid:client secret is there for all the users of the app, it doesn't uniquely identify a user. The whole point for such a system is to avoid the use of passwords and make sure only authorised applications can actually use it.

You can have something like a ValidateUser endpoint where you can post the username / password in addition to the token and that's where you can do whatever you're trying to do.

Just think really well what you are doing and most importantly why.